# Manipulator handles have ceased to function

Tags: workflow, edit-mode, versions

I recently downloaded Blender 2.74 on my linux. I’ll grab for the handles to manipulate an object. Unfortunately, all this does is throw my cursor off of it's position.
*Problem in a nutshell* when I click on the handles to move an object, they don't respond.
It's not *that* big of a problem, but it's something I'd like fixed.

**Note:** this doesn't happen on my Windows 7, 8, or any of my macs.

Comment: Your question is unnecessarily wordy and verbose, please simplify to your basic question and example.

Comment: <JK> party pooper <JK> what's verbose?

Comment: It literally means "using or expressed in more words than are needed." Cool word huh? :D

Comment: This could be one of those odd OS incompatibilities. There is no specific Linux build, so maybe that is the issue.

Comment: it said Linux/GNU, so I assumed it was for Linux or gnu.

Comment: Just so you don't think you're going crazy, i've experienced this too on linux. In later builds from https://builder.blender.org/download/ this problem seems to have disappeared.

Comment: @VinceScalia My bad, they do support Linux now. That makes it even more odd though :/

Comment: ooohhh. yuck. a bug. *shivers*

Comment: You have one button on your viewport clicked when it shouldn't be. That is the problem.

Comment: ?what? mind explaining which one?